# Admin Design configuration does not save in Magento 2.1.0

Tags: magento2.1.0

I have installed fresh **magento 2.1.0** in my **wamp server 3.0** I have done with all changes required to install magento 2.1.0 in wamp and it's work fine.

Now I have created my theme on below path :
**D:\wamp\www\magento2.1\app\design\frontend\Ecommerce\m2-theme**

In my theme I have copied whole **D:\wamp\www\magento2.1\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma** folder and change 3 important files **theme.xml** , **registration.xml** and **composer.json**.

Now I go to **admin > content > design > configuration** and my theme is showing there for **Globle** , **Main website** and **main website store** but when I assign my theme and do save it's show me an error that

> Cannot read contents from file "D:/wamp/www/magento2.1/" Warning!file_get_contents(D:/wamp/www/magento2.1/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

After getting this error I googled for my issue and I find [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5288) and [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5666) links but no luck.

**So can anyone tell me what is the issue and how can I solve this issue?**

Answer (score 7):

Actually, it is related to the Email module as you can set the default Header and Footer templates for the Transactional Email in the last section of the configuration. And the issue is in the Email Module.

## Solution

Find the file `\vendor\magento\module-email\Model\AbstractTemplate.php` and on line number **672** replace the if condition `if ($storeId)` with `if ($storeId !== false)`.

## Explanation

When you are saving the Global Configuration for the Store, you can see in the url that the current scope id is **0** (`admin/theme/design_config/edit/scope/default/scope_id/0/`) **This is important**.

Now, when you save the configuration, Magento will try to validate the Header and Footer templates whether you change them or not, using the class `Magento\Theme\Model\Design\Config`. While doing so, Magento instantiates an object of class `\Magento\Email\Model\Template` which actually extends the class `\Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate`.

Using this template class, Magento tries to emulate the template for the current scope. This is where the issue lies. You can find the code for this at line **670** of **\Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate**.

> `public function emulateDesign($storeId, $area = self::DEFAULT_DESIGN_AREA)
>       {
>           if ($storeId) {
>               // save current design settings
>               $this->emulatedDesignConfig = clone $this->getDesignConfig();
>               if (
>                   $this->getDesignConfig()->getStore() != $storeId
>                   || $this->getDesignConfig()->getArea() != $area
>               ) {
>                   $this->setDesignConfig(['area' => $area, 'store' => $storeId]);
>                   $this->applyDesignConfig();
>               }
>           } else {
>               $this->emulatedDesignConfig = false;
>           }
>       }`

Since the `scope_id` for the Global scope is 0 (Note: `scope_id` is being passed as `storeId` here), `false` is returned and Magento starts to look into `adminhtml` for the templates. Now all you have to do is change the if condition from `if ($storeId)` to `if ($storeId !== false)` and you will be able to save the configuration.

Final Note: I know that editing the core file is bad practice. I have done this as a temporary solution hoping that this issue is fixed in the coming updates.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to copy the folder `\vendor\magento\module-email\view\frontend\email` to `\vendor\magento\module-email\view\adminhtml\email`. For some reason, it's looking in the `adminhtml` folder for the `header.html` file.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5288

This worked for me.

Comment: no it's not proper solution. it's not related to email module.so I am not excepting this answer.

Comment: @watson what about V.S solution?